# difference between subquadratic and quadratic algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am confused between a sub-quadratic and quadratic algorithm. I know quadratic is when the big O is n square. Then what is a sub-quadratic algorithm?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about growth rates of fucntions, not programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subquadratic designates an algorithm whose complexity is `~o(n^2)`, using the [little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). This means that the complexity grows much slower than `n^2`. It could be anything from linear to almost quadratic.

Answer (score 5):

In layman's terms it's anything between linear and quadratic for instance `n^2/logn`.